# Redux Saga - all the watches called for a dispatch action

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, saga

I have declared the following saga api.

```
export function* watchSaveProducts() {
  yield takeLatest(ProductActionTypes.PRODUCT_SAVE_REQUEST, saveProducts);
}

export const saga = function* productSagasContainer() {
  yield all([watchGetProducts(), watchSaveProducts()]);
};
```

When I dispatch an action from the container, both the saga watches triggered. But in that I am just calling only getProducts. Even If I do save products, then getProducts triggered before save products.

```
    componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getProducts();
  }
```

The dispatch props like follow

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  getProducts: () => dispatch(productActions.getProducts()),
  saveProduct: (ids: number[]) => dispatch(productActions.saveProduct(ids)),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're throwing both methods when you do this:

```
export const saga = function* productSagasContainer() {
  yield all([watchGetProducts(), watchSaveProducts()]);
};
```

Therefore, both will always be running.

I'll explain my structure when I work with redux and sagas:

1. First, **create a sagaMiddleware to connect redux-store with sagas** (extracted from the [redux-saga documentation](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/)) :

```
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import reducer from './path/to/reducer'

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  // Note: passing middleware as the last argument to createStore requires redux@>=3.1.0
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
  return {
    ...createStore(reducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(/* other middleware, */sagaMiddleware)),
    runSaga: sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
  }
}
```

2. Define **rootSaga with sagas divided into application parts**:

```
export function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([fork(sample1Watcher), fork(sample2Watcher)]);
}
```

3. Create the **set of sagas** that will be launched in this part **depending on the action that is dispatched**

```
export function* sample1Watcher() {
  yield takeLatest(ProductActionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_REQUEST, getProduct);
  yield takeLatest(ProductActionTypes.PRODUCT_SAVE_REQUEST, saveProduct);
}
```

4. Define **each of the methods**, for example the get:

```
function* getProduct() {
  try {
    yield put({ type: actionTypes.SET_PRODUCTS_LOADING });

    const data = yield call(products.fetchProductsAsync);

    yield put({ type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCTS_COMPLETE, payload: data });

  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error");
  }
}
```

5. Finally, define **action method in dispatchToProps and launch it wherever you want**:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  getProducts: () => dispatch(productActions.getProducts()),
  saveProduct: (ids: number[]) => dispatch(productActions.saveProduct(ids)),
});
```

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.getProducts();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this doesn't help

Comment: Could you add a codesandbox sample with your problem that can be reproduced?

Comment: It's my mistake. I have added duplicate action string. Since your answer is a good approach, I have done up vote. Thanks for your reply.